# remove the black horizontal shades from picture in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How can I remove the black horizontal shades from the picture:

Comment: please show some sample pictures when asking these kind of questions!

Comment: Try using an adaptive threshold algorithm.  Check out the post I linked to you above for code and some sample uses.

Answer (score 1):

Perform thresholding to binarize the image into black and white.  Should remove the gray areas.  It seems that a global threshold should work, but if not, try using a localized thresholding algorithm.

This is the result when doing:

```
imshow(~(I<95))
```

[image: Output image]

Comment: I tried the otsu method but it didnt help.

Comment: I added an example 1 line in matlab.  Obviously, more elaborate algorithms can produce better results.